# How to select `Group` rows that has at least 2 rows `Year` field biggest than 0?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select `Group` that has at least 2 rows `Year` field biggest than 0?
for example below table how to get the result is the `a` rows

Update

```
Group    Name    
a        a0      
a        a1      
a        a2      
b        b0      
b        b1 

Name    Year
a0      0
a1      1
a2      2
b0      0
b1      1
```

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE Year > 0`  at least 2 rows Year field biggest than 0  ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `group` FROM `table` WHERE `year` > '0' GROUP BY `group` HAVING COUNT(`group`) > '1'
```

Here GROUP BY will combine rows based on same value of group column and HAVING clause will make sure the `at least 2 rows` condition.

For the updated question, you need to use a JOIN (or LEFT JOIN), like this:

```
SELECT `group`
FROM `table1` JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`name` = `table2`.`name`
WHERE `year` > 0
GROUP BY `group` 
HAVING COUNT(`group`) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, What if I separate to 2 table like I update the question how to call the same result

Comment: @user1575921 I have updated my answer based on your edit of the question.